# Trouble figuring out the problems with recursive binary search in C

Tags: c, recursion

I am having trouble understanding why my code is returning segmentation errors when I test it. I am trying to learn recursion, and C and I would be grateful if someone could show me where I am wrong.
Here it is:

```
// Binary search through numbers using recursion.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//prototype
bool search(int n, int array[], int lower, int upper);

int main(void) {
    int elements;
    //getting a list of numbers from the user
    printf("How many elements are in the array?:");
    scanf("%d", &elements);
    printf("Please type the elements:");
    int array[elements];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    //printing out the array elements typed
    printf("The array is: ");
    for (int k = 0, arraylen = elements; k < arraylen; k++)
        printf("%d ", array[k]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("What number do you wish to search?");
    int item;
    scanf("%d", &item);
    bool result = search(item, array, array[0], array[elements]);
    if (result) {
        printf("Number found.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Number not found.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

bool search(int n, int array[], int lower, int upper) {
    //base case
    if (upper < lower) {
        return false;
    }

    int midpoint = (upper + lower) / 2;
    if (n == array[midpoint]) {
        return true;
    }
    /** If value searched for is greater than the value at midpoint,  then
        Then discard everything to the left of a sorted list. **/
    else if (n > array[midpoint]) {
        //lower becomes midpoint + 1
        return search(n, array, (midpoint + 1), upper);
    }
    /** If value searched for is less than the value at midpoint, then
        Then discard everything to the right of a sorted list. **/    
    else if (n < array[midpoint]) {
        //upper becomes midpoint - 1
        return search(n, array, lower, (midpoint - 1));
    }
}
```

When I run it, this happens:

```
./bin_search 
How many elements are in the array?:5
Please type the elements:1 2 3 45 46
The array is: 1 2 3 45 46 
What number do you wish to search?45
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `search` return something? There are two branches where it doesn't which will lead to *undefined behavior*. The compiler should have warned you about it.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Correcting.

Comment: Also, if you have an array of `elements` number of elements, what is the highest possible index you can use then? Hint: it's *not* `elements`.

Comment: Finally, shouldn't you be passing *indexes* to the initial call to `search`?

Comment: the code does not quite compile.  the compiler outputs the message: 
"60:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"  You need to fix that logic problem before doing any other debugging.

Comment: to perform a binary search, the elements must be in sorted (probably ascending) order.   Never trust the user to properly enter the elements in sorted order.  So the posted code is missing the logic to sort the array, after the user enters the array, before searching the array.

Comment: the code block, beginning with this line: `else if (n < array[midpoint])`  can be reduced to: `return search(n, array, lower, (midpoint - 1));` --or-- `else return search(n, array, lower, (midpoint - 1));`  as all other cases are already handled.   This will also fix the compile warning

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  For the posted code, the only `success` returned value is 1.   `scanf()`, when successful will return a count that matches the number of format specifiers in the format string.

Comment: what happens when the value to find is less than array[0]?  what happens when the value to find is greater than array[elements-1]?   what happens when the value to find is between two adjacent values in the array?

Comment: Actually the code has always compiled, I used gcc with make. Thanks for the breakdowns, much appreciated! How do you check the return values for scanf though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the array boundary indices, not the elements:

```
bool result = search(item, array, 0, elements);
```

Your current code invokes undefined behavior: `search(item, array, array[0], array[elements])` passes `array[elements]` as the upper boundary, reading past the end of the `array`, probably a very large number that causes the `search` function to reference an invalid address, causing the `Segmentation fault`.

Also these boundaries are not handled correctly in the search function: `upper` is **excluded**, so the initial test should be `if (upper <= lower) return false;`, and when you recurse on the left half, you should use `midpoint` as the upper boundary, not `midpoint-1`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
bool search(int n, int array[], int lower, int upper) {
    //base case
    if (upper <= lower)
        return false;

    int midpoint = (upper + lower) / 2;
    if (n == array[midpoint])
        return true;

    /** If value searched for is greater than the value at midpoint,  then
        Then discard everything to the left of a sorted list. **/
    if (n > array[midpoint]) {
        //lower becomes midpoint + 1
        return search(n, array, midpoint + 1, upper);
    }
    /** If value searched for is less than the value at midpoint, then
        Then discard everything to the right of a sorted list. **/    
    //upper becomes midpoint - 1
    return search(n, array, lower, midpoint);
}
```

Note that you need a way to know the index for the match, a solution would be to return this index and return `-1` for no match.

Answer (score 0):

`lower` and `upper` should be indexes, instead of values.

```
// Binary search through numbers using recursion.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//prototype
bool search(int n, int array[], int lower, int upper);

int main(void) {
    int elements;
    //getting a list of numbers from the user
    printf("How many elements are in the array?:");
    scanf("%d", &elements);
    printf("Please type the elements:");
    int array[elements];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    //printing out the array elements typed
    printf("The array is: ");
    for (int k = 0, arraylen = elements; k < arraylen; k++)
        printf("%d ", array[k]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("What number do you wish to search?");
    int item;
    scanf("%d", &item);
    bool result = search(item, array, 0, elements-1);
    if (result) {
        printf("Number found.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Number not found.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

bool search(int n, int array[], int lower, int upper) {
    if (upper < lower) {
        return false;
    }

    int midpoint = (upper + lower) / 2;

    if (n == array[midpoint]) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (n > array[midpoint]) {
        search(n, array, (midpoint + 1), upper);
    }
    else {
        search(n, array, lower, (midpoint - 1));
    }
}
```

And the reason why you got a segfault is that `array[array[5]]` may be beyond the scope of `array`, whose type is `int (*)[5]`, causing undefined behavior.(In fact, dereferencing array[5] itself causes undefined behavior, as pointed out by chqrlie.)

Comment: There are other problems in the `search` function which may cause  incorrect results and in some cases undefined behavior.

Comment: Your explanation for the crash in not strictly correct: the program does not reference `array[45]`, the value passed for the upper boundary is itself an invalid reference `array[5]`, just past the end of the defined array.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, you are right, but I think just changing `elements` to `elements-1` is OK.

Comment: Yes, it fixes the problem, but it is less idiomatic for C than to exclude the upper bound:  it also requires for the indices to be signed to express an empty array has having boudaries `0` and `-1`, which poses a problem if you change the type for the indices to be `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
I did nt try this
you can call the following function

```
bool result = search(item, array, 0, lenth_of_array - 1);
```

search function like this

```
bool search(int item, int array[], int start, int end){

   if(start>end){
      return false;
   }
   int mid = (start+end)/2;
   if(array[mid]==item){
       return true;
   }

   else if(array[mid]>item){
       return search(item, array, start, mid-1);
   }

   else if(array[mid]<item){
       return search(item, array,mid+1,end);
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you pass a `startingIndex` and `lastIndex` from the `main` function?

Comment: How does your function differ from the OPs?

Comment: startingIndex=0
    lastIndex = lenth_of_array -1

check Edit

Comment: Invoked as per the edit, you fix the problem, but your `search` function is exactly identical as the OPs with different argument names.  As a matter of fact, it should be invoked as `bool result = search(item, array, 0, elements - 1); `.